# tableGrob: set the height and width of a grid.table

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I'm trying to make a function that will give me a plot ready for indesign, illustrator or inkscape. In trying to do so, I have 2 problems I cannot solve.

1) set the width and height of my plot (or just the grobTable): 
The output I get is very small and when upscaling it in illustrator the font follows and become way to big. Therefore I want to make plots with manually defined widths and heights.

2) Sometimes the title, note and rownames gets "misplaced" (see the difference between plot 1 and 2 for details). It happens when the rownames are short.

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

data(diamonds)

## plot function

kryds.row <- function(x,y, p=100, decor="%", digits=3,
                  titel="", note="", red=219, green=55, blue= 153){

c <- table(x, y)
s <- as.character(sum(c))
s <- paste("Antal svarpersoner=", s, sep=" ")
j <- prop.table(c,1)
r <- c(rownames(j),"Total")
k <- c(colnames(j), "Total")
j <- addmargins(j, margin =2, FUN = sum)
j <- round(j, digits)
j[]<-paste(j*p, decor, sep=" ")

farve <- rgb(red,green,blue, maxColorValue =255)

table     <-   tableGrob(j,
                       cols = k,
                       gpar.coretext = gpar(fontsize = 12),            
                       gpar.coltext  = gpar(fontsize = 12,col="white"),            
                       gpar.rowtext  = gpar(fontsize = 12, fontface="bold"),            
                       gpar.corefill = gpar(fill = rgb(255,255,255, maxColorValue      =255), alpha = 1, col = NA),
                       gpar.rowfill  = gpar(fill = rgb(255,255,255, maxColorValue =255), alpha = 1, col = NA),           
                       gpar.colfill  = gpar(fill = 0, alpha = 1 ,col= "white"),                       
                       equal.width   = TRUE,            
                       show.rownames = TRUE,            
                       show.rsep     = TRUE, 
                       show.hlines   = TRUE,                               
                       show.csep     = FALSE, 
                       show.vlines   = FALSE,
                       show.box      = FALSE,
                       padding.h     = unit(15, "mm"),            
                       padding.v     = unit(8, "mm"),
                       core.just     = "center", 
                       row.just      = "left",
                       separator     = farve)


 hh <- grobHeight(table)
 ww <- grobWidth(table)

 border <- roundrectGrob(x=0.5, y=0.5, width=ww, height=hh,
                      default.units="npc",
                      r=unit(0.1, "snpc"),
                      just="centre",
                      name=NULL, gp=gpar(col="white", fill=farve, vp=NULL)) 

 border2 <- roundrectGrob(x=0.5, y=0.5, width=ww, height=hh,
                       default.units="npc",
                       r=unit(0.1, "snpc"),
                       just="centre",
                       name=NULL, gp=gpar(fill=NA, col=farve, vp=NULL))

 title <- textGrob(titel,
                x=unit(0.5,"npc") -0.5*ww + unit(5, "mm"), 
                y=unit(0.5,"npc") +0.5*hh + unit(2, "mm"), 
                vjust=0,hjust=0, gp=gpar(fontsize=12, fontface="bold"))

 footnote <- textGrob(note, 
                   x=unit(0.5,"npc") - 0.5*ww + unit(5,"mm"),
                   y=unit(0.5,"npc") - 0.5*hh, 
                   vjust=1, hjust=0,gp=gpar( fontsize=10))

 svarpersoner       <- textGrob(s, 
                             x=unit(0.5,"npc") + 0.5*ww -unit(5, "mm"),
                             y=unit(0.5,"npc") + 0.5*hh + unit(2, "mm"), 
                             vjust=0, hjust=1,gp=gpar( fontsize=10))
 grid.newpage()
 gt <- gTree(children=gList(border,table,border2, title, footnote, svarpersoner))
 grid.draw(gt)

}



# Plot it 
kryds.row(diamonds$color, diamonds$cut, titel="title", note="note") # plot 1
kryds.row(diamonds$cut, diamonds$color, titel="title", note="note") # plot 2


# Problems
#1: The title, note and the j in the row.text is very badly placed in plot 1 but not   plot 2
#2 I cannot set the width and height of my table
```

I have not cleaned up in my code yet, so please bare with it!

Comment: 1. the default justification for row labels is left, you could change that to centered. 2. There's no option to set the table size, unfortunately, it is calculated to fit the content, and will therefore change depending on the font size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I went with was to manipulate the length of the levels like this:

```
 longest <- 0
 longestnumber <- 0

 for (i in 1:length(levels(x))){

  if (longest < nchar(levels(x))[i]){
  longest <- nchar(levels(x))[i] 
  longestnumber <- i
  } 
   }

 for (i in 1:(100-longest)){
  levels(x)[longestnumber] <- paste(levels(x)[longestnumber], " ", sep="")
  }
```

That way I can control the width of the table

Comment: @Baptiste is the width af a Tablegrob dependent on how many rows it has?

Answer (score 5):

The current version of gridExtra::tableGrob doesn't let you set the widths/heights. You can however try a different [(experimental)](https://github.com/baptiste/tablegrob) version of tableGrob built from scratch using gtable.

```
#library(devtools)
#install_github("tablegrob", "baptiste")
require(tablegrob)

d <- iris[sample(seq.int(nrow(iris)), 6),]

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(height=0.8,width=0.9))
g2 <- tableGrob(d, rows=NULL,
                widths=unit(1,"null"), heights=unit(1/(nrow(d)),"npc"))
grid.draw(g2)
grid.roundrect(y=unit(0,"line"), height=unit(1,"npc") +unit(1,"lines"),
               just="bottom", r=unit(0.05, "snpc"))
```

Edit (08/2015): you can now edit the widths/heights, since grid.table is now based on gtable.