# Two font faces in grid.tables

Tags: r, font-face, r-grid

I have created a `grid.table` object to display a dataframe in PowerBi, below there is my code:

```
library(reshape)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
mydf <- data.frame(id = c(1:5), value = c("A","B","C","D","E"))
mytheme <- ttheme_default(base_size = 10,
                          core=list(fg_params=list(hjust=0, x=0.01),
                                    bg_params=list(fill=c("white", "lightgrey"))))

grid.table(mydf,cols = NULL, theme = mytheme, rows = NULL)
```

and this is my output:

[image]

I would like to style the font of the output so that only the first column has the font in bold, does anyone knows how to achive this?

Thanks

Comment: Just FYI: non-Windows SO folks aren't going to have that font by default.

Comment: ok, @hrbrmstr I removed the font type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grid.table()` is just a wrapper for `grid.draw(tableGrob(...))`

You can get your desired results with some Grob surgery:

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

mydf <- data.frame(id = c(1:5), value = c("A","B","C","D","E"))

mytheme <- ttheme_default(base_size = 10, 
                          core = list(fg_params=list(hjust=0, x=0.01),
                                      bg_params=list(fill=c("white", "lightgrey"))))
```

Make the `tableGrob`:

```
tg <- tableGrob(mydf, cols = NULL, theme = mytheme, rows = NULL)
```

Edit the `tableGrob` (column 1 is first 5 slots):

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  tg$grobs[[i]] <- editGrob(tg$grobs[[i]], gp=gpar(fontface="bold"))
}
```

I like to use a new page for examples , but you can remove it since `grid.table()` doesn't use it either:

```
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(tg)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! Sorry @hrbrmstr I have another question, can I set a specific column width? It is possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471808/tablegrob-set-the-height-and-width-of-a-grid-table

Comment: Yes, I saw that question, but the solution does not work. 
Is it not possible to set the width of the column to change according to the maximum length of the string contained in that column?

Comment: technically it's a new question. I won't edit my answer but if you can follow this w/o expository, then you won't need to open a new question `space <- 30 ; tg$widths[1] <- unit(max(unlist(lapply(tg$grobs[1:5], function(g) {convertWidth(grobWidth(g), "pt", TRUE)}))) + space, "pt")`

Comment: sorry, how I can set  only the first column has the font in bold if I use the statement `grid.table()` and therefore I do not create a  `grob` object? Sorry If you want I put another question for this, thanks for your help!

Comment: Look at the source for `grid.table` if you don't believe the first line in my answer. It literally makes the grob and calls `grid.draw`. What is the issue just doing those two things on your own?

Comment: sorry it's my english fault. I perfectly understood what you wanted to tell me in the first answer, but I need to use the statement `grid.table()` without creating a `grob` object. So I need to use `grid.table(data.frame)` and set the bold font for the first column. Sorry but powerBI doesn't accept the statement `grid.draw`. I hope I have been clearer now