# Two font faces in grid.tables whitout using grid.draw()

Tags: r, grid, font-face

A few days ago I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266712/two-font-faces-in-grid-tables) where he gave me a lot of help @hrbrmstr.

I perfectly understood that `grid.table()` is just a wrapper for `grid.draw(tableGrob(...))`, but now I encountered another kind of problem:

when I publish my report on app.powerbi, PowerBI doesn't accept the statement `grid.draw()`.

In other words, I need to create a grid table object without creating a `grob` object.

I did this in this way:

```
my.dataframe <- data.frame(BDS_ID = c("001","002"),
                           PRIORITY = c("high","medium"),
                           STATUS = c("onair","onair"),
                           COMPANY = c("airfr","fly"))
mytheme <- ttheme_default(core=list(
           fg_params=list(fontface="bold"),
           bg_params = list(fill=c("grey95", "grey90"))
))
grid.table(my.dataframe, theme = mytheme, rows = NULL)
```

but I need to change the layout of `grid.table` setting the bold font only for the first column.

Does anyone knows how to achive this?

Thanks